# How to min_max normalize data

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, classification

In the context of K-Nearest Neighbors classification I needed to min-max normalize multiple values in a dictionary. I did it by taking the values, splitting them in separate lists, run the min-max normalize function on these lists and zipped the lists together again. See below. I guess there are smarter ways to do it ?

```
dataset = {'a':[1, 200], 'b':[1.5, 180], 'c':[0.8, 80], 'd':[1.2, 150]}
values = dataset.values()
value_1 = [i[0] for i in values] 
value_2 = [i[1] for i in values]

def min_max_normalize(lst):
  minimum = min(lst)
  maximum = max(lst)
  normalized = []
  for i in range(len(dataset)):
    normalized_value = (lst[i] - minimum)/(maximum - minimum)
    normalized.append(normalized_value)
  return normalized

value_1_normalized = min_max_normalize(value_1)
value_2_normalized = min_max_normalize(value_2)
values_normalized = zip(value_1_normalized, value_2_normalized)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a [`MinMaxScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) from scikit-learn?

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
dataset = {'a':[1, 200], 'b':[1.5, 180], 'c':[0.8, 80], 'd':[1.2, 150]}
vals = list(dataset.values())
scl = MinMaxScaler().fit(vals)
scl.transform(vals)
# array([[0.28571429, 1.        ],
#        [1.        , 0.83333333],
#        [0.        , 0.        ],
#        [0.57142857, 0.58333333]])
```

Remember to only fit your train set, and then you can apply the `scl.transform` to your test set.